# What is an algorithm for what I am trying to do?

Tags: algorithms

I have an equation $y=2x^4-20x^2-50x$ within a range of -4 to 6

I already have an algorithim that tell me the y value when I plug in the $x$. It simply uses a loop.

What I am trying to do is determine what will be be the y max value and what $x$ corresponds to it.
Is there some sort of loop or counter I can use. I am program this on SPARC machine but any sort of pseucode loop will be appreciated.

I tried to do the following

I have a counter

Comment: If I understand correctly then you need to look for derivative and check for root to determine global/local max. This doesn't need computer.

Comment: Why do you need a loop to calculate `2*x*x*x*x - 20*x*x - 50*x`?

Comment: How would you calculate the maximum of a list or array? ("I have a counter" is not much of a start; of course you have some, assuming you have a Turing complete language.) Are you interested in real x or integer x?

Comment: real integer x is what im interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the local maxima and minima by taking the derivative and setting it to 0.  This leaves you with a non-linear equation $f'(x)=0$ to solve.

The easiest, and most reliable, way to find the zeros of a continuous non-linear equation, $g(x)=0$, is called the [Bisection Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

Find two points $x_-$ and $x_+$ where $g(x_-) < 0$ and $g(x_+) > 0$.  (These are particularly easy to find for odd-degree polynomials, since there will always be at least one real root.)

Now evaluate $g(x_\star)$ where $x_\star = (x_- + x_+)/2$.  If $g(x_\star) > 0$ then let $x_+ = x_\star$ and repeat.  Else if $g(x_\star) < 0$ then let $x_- = x_\star$ and repeat.

Because you are interested in the range [-4,6] you also need to evaluate $f(-4)$ and $f(6)$, because the local maxima may not be inside the range.  (Your function obviously has no finite global maximum. $f(10)$ is about 18000, and grows from there and $f(-10)$ is also about 18000 and grows from there.